# Create "Draft" Email In Pardot API

Tags: rest-api, email, api, email-template, pardot

I have a tool that builds emails and can send through various ESPs like Pardot (sand Salesforce Marketing Cloud). I see the API endpoints for sending emails (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/pardot/guide/emails-v4.html) but I don't see how I can create an email as a draft in Pardot - so the user can then go into Pardot and configure more advanced settings there before sending.

Is this possible?  Can you create email objects via the API?

Answer (score 0):

You can't really create the email in "draft" status with the API. One workaround that might work for you is scheduling the email to send weeks/months into the future, then a human can go in and make the necessary changes.